# Running a program with a batch and keyboard input

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm working on a batch file that will take keyboard input and then launch different stuff depending on what i choose. I have the following what i do not get runnin: The cd and start work when they are alone but not with the go to part.

```
set /p %environment%=Goede dag Jeroen! Wilt u beginnen met FME(f), 
AutoCAD(a), beide(b) of alleen opstart(g)? f/a/b/g :

IF /i "%environment%" == "f" GOTO work
IF /i "%environment%" == "a" GOTO cadprog
IF /i "%environment%" == "b" GOTO same
IF /i "%environment%" == "g" GOTO geen
ECHO "Ongeldige keuze. Kies alstublief opnieuw"
GOTO end

:work 
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\FME"
start fmeworkbench.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
start chrome.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
start firefox.exe

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe W:\DataService\Colo

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe W:\DataService\Colo
goto end

:cadprog
cd "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD Map 3D 2012"
start acad.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
start chrome.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
start firefox.exe

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe W:\DataService\Colo

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe W:\DataService\Colo
goto end

:same
cd "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD Map 3D 2012"
start acad.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\FME"
start fmeworkbench.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
start chrome.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
start firefox.exe

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe W:\DataService\Colo

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe W:\DataService\Colo
goto end

:geen
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
start chrome.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
start firefox.exe

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe W:\DataService\Colo

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe W:\DataService\Colo

:end
PAUSE
```

Comment: You do not use percent symbols to assign a value to a variable.  You only use percent symbols when you need to reference the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix first line:

```
set /p environment=Goede dag Jeroen! Wilt u beginnen met FME(f), AutoCAD(a), beide(b) of alleen opstart(g)? f/a/b/g :
```